# File Creation/Loop Problems in Ruby

Tags: ruby

EDIT: My original question was way off, my apologies. Mark Reed has helped me find out the real problem, so here it is.

Note that this code works:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

source_url = "www.flickr.com"
puts "Visiting #{source_url}"
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://website/script.php?value=#{source_url}"))
textarea = page.css('textarea') 


filename = source_url.to_s + ".txt"
create_file = File.open("#{filename}", 'w')
create_file.puts textarea
create_file.close
```

Which is really awesome, but I need it to do this to ~110 URLs, not just Flickr. Here's my loop that isn't working:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

File.open('sources.txt').each_line do |source_url|
  puts "Visiting #{source_url}"
  page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://website/script.php?value=#{source_url}"))
  textarea = page.css('textarea') 

  filename = source_url.to_s + ".txt"
  create_file = File.open("#{filename}", 'w')
  create_file.puts "#{textarea}"
  create_file.close
end
```

What am I doing wrong with my loop?

Comment: The correct syntax is `File.open(variable, 'w')`.  what is the contents of `variable`?

Comment: I've added the full code - variable = source_url

Comment: What is the value when it fails, though?  Can you create a file with that name in that folder via other means?

Comment: I believe it's "www.flickr.com". Creating "www.flickr.com.txt" works perfectly fine manually.

Comment: but there's no '.txt' above.  try just doing File.open("www.flickr.com","w") from irb and see what you get. I suspect Windows just doesn't like that as a filename.  But if that works, it's probably time for a chat instead of more comments.

Comment: Completely re-edited everything in main post. I've looked on your profile and I have no idea how to PM or chat or anything, so please do initiate it! I'd be happy to delete my comments if it makes the thread  more readable.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10905/discussion-between-stn-and-mark-reed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, now you're looping over the lines of the input file.  When you do that, you get strings that end in a newilne.  So you're trying to create a file with a newline in the middle of its name, which is not legal in Windows.

Just chomp the string:

```
File.open('sources.txt').each_line do |source_url|
  source_url.chomp!
  # ... rest of code goes here ...
```

You can also use `File#foreach` instead of `File#open.each_line`:

```
File.foreach('sources.txt') do |source_url|
  source_url.chomp!
  # ... rest of code goes here
```

Comment: Low-tech way to debug these sorts of problems is just to add `puts` - you were printing out the URL, but you would have seen the problem right away if you printed out the actual entire  filename right before the open call.

Answer (score 0):

You're putting your parentheses in the wrong place:

```
create_file = File.open(variable, 'w')
```

Comment: Thanks. Changed. Still getting the same error though. Edited post to contain full code, maybe this isn't the issue.